# Why does this dynamic allocation of type char** and char* using malloc segfault?

Tags: c, dynamic, segmentation-fault, malloc, allocation

I don't understand why this code segmentation faults. It can work if I define a char** inside of the function, allocate to that char**, then point *commandsArray at that char**. Can someone explain what I am not understanding? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void input_str_to_sngl_commands( char*** commandsArray );

int main()
{

    char** commandsArray_var;
    input_str_to_sngl_commands( &commandsArray_var );

return 0;
}

void input_str_to_sngl_commands( char*** commandsArray )
{
    *commandsArray = (char**) malloc(2*sizeof(char**));
    *commandsArray[0] = (char*) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    *commandsArray[1] = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the precedence wrong: `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, so `*commandsArray[1]` accesses a wrong address.

Use parentheses to force evaluation order, like this

```
*commandsArray = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
(*commandsArray)[0] = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
(*commandsArray)[1] = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

or use a temporary variable to use a more readable syntax:

```
char** ret = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
ret[0] = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
ret[1] = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
*commandsArray = ret;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/GOfMXB)

**Note:** [Casting `malloc` is unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/335858).

Answer (score 0):

`*commandsArray[1]` is the same as `*(commandsArray[1])`, but what you wanted here was `(*commandsArray)[1]`.

`commandsArray[1]` is the memory after the `commandsArray_var` (which contains garbage as far as you are concerned), treated as a `char*`.

`*commandsArray[1]` tries to dereference the garbage `char*`, which segfaults.

All you need to do is add parentheses - make it `(*commandsArray)[1]`.

This also affects the previous line, which uses `*commandsArray[0]`, but coincidentally (since `*x == x[0]`), `(*commandsArray)[0]` is the same as `*(commandsArray[0])` (and both are the same as `**commandsArray`). You should add the parentheses to that line as well anyway, to make it clear what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`*commandsArray[0]` should be `(*commandsArray)[0]`.

Also, you malloc the wrong amount of space. The chance of making this mistake can be reduced by using a `sizeof` expression that corresponds to the type being pointed to by the pointer you are creating, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Using a temporary pointer as suggested by dasblinkenlight is a great idea too. This makes it easier to clean up from allocation failure and easier to read your code:

```
char **new;

new = malloc( 2 * sizeof *new );
new[0] = malloc( 30 * sizeof **new );
new[1] = malloc( 30 * sizeof **new );

*commandsArray = new;
```